# Firebase Firestore - sharing content through email

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a Firebase web app with a Firestore database. In my app, there's an ability to share some content, let's call it `topics`.
I wonder what would be the best approach here when considering a scenario where userA shares something with userB, who does not have an account yet.

I'm thinking the following - `userA` want to share a topic with `userB`, so he provides the email of `userB`. Email is being sent to `userB`; he enters the link in an email and to see the topic, he needs to create an account with that particular email (Because of security rules being applied to topics, based on email).

Everything seems straightforward, but the problem with this approach is that I also have different providers allowed to log in. For example, `userB` with email `xxxx@example.com` goes to the link and has the ability to log in through Google provider. `UserB` can have multiple accounts inside the Google sign-in provider, and he can choose a different email, let's say `yyyy@gmail.com`, and then the security rules will not be fulfilled.

I wonder if there are some tips or even different approaches to handling that problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict `userB` to access the `topics` only if it joins the app with `xxxx@example.com` then you have two options available.

The first option will be to redirect `userB` when it clicks the link in the email to a screen where the email is autocompleted and cannot be changed. This means that the user should only choose a password in order to join the app. However, it's not quite a bulletproof solution, because if the user goes to other pages of your website, he will be able to choose another sign-in option with another provider and use another email address.

The second solution will be when you send the invitation to `userB` by email, to store a key-value pair in [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) or in the [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore). For this simple example let's use the Realtime Database because the write operation is free of charge:

```
db
|
--- invitations
      |
      --- $pushedKey: "xxxx@example.com"
```

As you can see, the key is random, as it is generated by the `push()` function from the Realtime Database, while the value is the email address. Now, when the user tries to join the app, you have to check the email against the random key. If you have a match, basically the email that the user tries to use is the one that is associated with the key, then you can let the user see the `topics`, otherwise display a message to inform the user that he needs to use the right email address, which in this case is `xxxx@example.com`.

Comment: The first approach is also broken because userB can already have an account connected with Google Provider - then, hardcoding email in the form to login using email provider with specific email won't work. 

So basically the solution is to store somehow the invitation and based on that inform user that he needs use the particular email. 

I also thought about restricting google sign-in to only one email (the one from invitation) but I think that's probably not possible at all.

Comment: In that case, you can go ahead with the second solution.

Comment: Hey Ziggy. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?